# How to get last 5 years and next year in Java

Tags: java

I want to get the last 5 years from the current year and next year from the current year in Java. All those value needs to be stored in an array .The intent is to only allow a total of 7 years as options.  So for 2018, the array would show 2012-2018.  And then in 2019, the array would show 2013-2019 and so on.]

Below code i have tried but not able to figure out how to store in array :

```
Integer currentYear = gregorianDate.getYear();
 Integer newYear = currentYear+1;
 Integer prevYear = currentYear-1;
```

Comment: I have downvoted this question because it appears to be a zero-effort requirements dump.  If you can [edit] your question to show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt, or to clarify *precisely* where you are having difficulty, this downvote may be retracted.

Comment: @JoeC this is what i tried but not able to figure out how to store in array :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it this way I suppose:

```
Integer currentYear = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR) + 1;
int[] yearsSpan = new int[7];
for (int i = 7; i > 0; i--) {
    yearsSpan[7-i] = currentYear - (i-1); 
}
```

To quickly display array contents:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(yearsSpan));
```